# Getting events while using Qt Designer

Tags: python

I am developing an application which uses treeview. Initially, I used Qt designer for the GUI and after, compiled the ui file into python. Until now everything was just fine. Now I want to copy and paste the file on pressing Copy and Paste buttons simultaneously. 
I watched and read many tutorials but they used re implementation of `QPushButton`. I can't adopt this technique because I used designer to create GUI and cant make changes in that file. Please help me to figure out that how can i use `QEvents` of my treeview. 
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Nope, your question is absolutely impossible to understand for anyone who doesn't actually have your code behing his eyes.